# I cannot see the Tables in my database Informix with NetBeans and I cannot do all SQL statement

Tags: netbeans, informix

I can't see the Tables in my Informix database with NetBeans and I can't do some query with Left, Right, inner... join What can I do?

[image]

My LOG File looks like this. I can create or drop Tables but cannot do  Join statements.

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:informix-    sqli://192.168.1.10:1521//usr/projects/dbs/f0001:INFORMIXSERVER=informixse;user=Odbc;password=        odbc;APPENDISAM=1;IFX_SET_FLOAT_AS_SMFLOAT=1;TRUSTED_CONTEXT=1;IFX_ISOLATION_LEVEL=8U;ssl    Connection=1;SQLIDEBUG=c:\Temp\sqlidebug_informix.trace")
    trying com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver
SQLWarning: reason(Umwandlung von Datentyp FLOAT in DECIMAL verwendet)     SQLState(01I05)
getConnection returning com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver
SQLState(42000) vendor code(-201)
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: A syntax error has occurred.
    at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.buildException(IfxErrMsg.java:465)
    at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:443)
    at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:394)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.addException(IfxSqli.java:3191)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.receiveError(IfxSqli.java:3472)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.dispatchMsg(IfxSqli.java:2379)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.receiveMessage(IfxSqli.java:2304)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.executeStatementQuery(IfxSqli.java:1522)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.executeStatementQuery(IfxSqli.java:1502)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxResultSet.executeQuery(IfxResultSet.java:218)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxStatement.executeQueryImpl(IfxStatement.java:1054)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxStatement.executeQuery(IfxStatement.java:227)
    at Drivers.InformixConnection.GetConnection(InformixConnection.java:57)
    at Views.User.Login.formWindowOpened(Login.java:413)
    at Views.User.Login.access$100(Login.java:44)
    at Views.User.Login$1.windowOpened(Login.java:117)
    at java.awt.Window.processWindowEvent(Window.java:2051)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.processWindowEvent(JFrame.java:305)
    at java.awt.Window.processEvent(Window.java:2013)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at     java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionD    omain.java:76)
    at     java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionD    omain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)    
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at     java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionD    omain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at     java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at     java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
SQLState(00000) vendor code(0)
java.sql.SQLException
at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.buildException(IfxErrMsg.java:474)
at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:443)
at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:394)
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.receiveError(IfxSqli.java:3477)
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.dispatchMsg(IfxSqli.java:2379)
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.receiveMessage(IfxSqli.java:2304)
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.executeStatementQuery(IfxSqli.java:1522)
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.executeStatementQuery(IfxSqli.java:1502)
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxResultSet.executeQuery(IfxResultSet.java:218)
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxStatement.executeQueryImpl(IfxStatement.java:1054)
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxStatement.executeQuery(IfxStatement.java:227)
at Drivers.InformixConnection.GetConnection(InformixConnection.java:57)
at Views.User.Login.formWindowOpened(Login.java:413)
at Views.User.Login.access$100(Login.java:44)
at Views.User.Login$1.windowOpened(Login.java:117)
at java.awt.Window.processWindowEvent(Window.java:2051)
at javax.swing.JFrame.processWindowEvent(JFrame.java:305)
at java.awt.Window.processEvent(Window.java:2013)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
registerDriver: com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver@4ffc81de
```

Comment: Hello Saab, welcome to StackOverflow! This question is too broad as we do not know how the internal system of your company works. As first guess, I would say you lack permissions for the things you want to do.

Comment: Please do [not post images of code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the queries you tried (as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) and the error message you got - ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: how can I edit  the permissions with my situation ?

Comment: If you can create and drop tables, then you have basic connectivity to the database.  You say you can't use JOIN notation — that's surprising, but you don't show the text (or even, AFAICS, an image) of a failing SELECT statement with join notation.  A key piece of information will be which version of Informix you're connected to.  The JOIN notation was added relatively recently (last 20 years); if you're using a really old database (I came across a 30-year old Informix system recently), you might have problems.  Try `SELECT DBINFO('version','full') FROM 'informix'.systables WHERE tabid = 1`.

Comment: **version 65537**

Comment: [Exception, Error code -253, SQLState IX000] Identifier length exceeds the 
      maximum allowed by this version of the server.
       Line 11, column 6

Execution finished after 0,078 s, 1 error occurred.

Comment: maybe I have problem with Informixserver **informixse**? `jdbc:informix-sqli://192.168.1.10:1521//usr/projects/dbs/f0001:INFORMIXSERVER=informixse`

Comment: because when I change it to something else that workes like the same situation

Comment: It could be because you are connecting to a Standard Engine. I tried that NetBeans DB explorer plugin against an IDS 12.10 and it  showed me all the tables.
Have you try adding "USEV5SERVER=1" to the connection string? It's one of the properties that should be used when connecting to an Informix SE server.

Comment: thank you for tips  that show System Tables Folder (without tables) but that like we will find some solution at the next :)

Comment: I tried  to download DB explorer plugin I did not find anyone, do you have one link or whitch one for you is the best ?

Comment: I don't know if the protocol allow to do that becuse this IDS is with sesoctcp protocol and it has the version 3.70.JC2DE .... some ideas ??

Comment: 3.70 is pretty old. Try 4.10.JC12. You can download directly form maven:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.informix/jdbc/4.10.12